# Partial view data doesn't get saved in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I create class `Project` in project class I define technology and another i define Class `Technology` I seed data in technology and after that i create dropdown list in Project `Create` view using a partial view and when I save data the technology can not be saved

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string? ProjectName { get; set; }

    public string? Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime? End { get; set; }

    public string? ProjectHead { get; set; }
    public string? Status { get; set; }
    public string? Technology { get; set; }
}

public class Technology
{
    public int TechnologyId { get; set; }
    public string? TechnologyName { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ProjectId,ProjectName,Description,Start,End,ProjectHead,Status,Technology")] Project project)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(project);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        return View(project);
}
```

This is my view of project create:

```
<div class="row">
        <partial name="_Technologypartial" />
</div>
```

technology Patial

```
@model TeamManagement.Models.Technology

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label>Technology</label>
        <br />
        <select asp-for="TechnologyId" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.Technology,"TechnologyId","TechnologyName"))">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

---

### EDIT

***View***

```
<div class="row">
        <partial name="_Technologypartial" model="@Model.technology" />
    </div>
```

***Controller***

```
 {
            var list = _context.Technology.ToList();

            List<SelectListItem> dropdown = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                dropdown.Add(new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = item.TechnologyName,
                    Value = item.TechnologyId.ToString()
                });
            }

            PartialViewData model = new PartialViewData();
            ViewBag.Technology = dropdown;
            return View(model);
        }

[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(PartialViewData model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Project project = new Project()
                {
                    ProjectId = model.project.ProjectId,
                    ProjectName = model.project.ProjectName,
                    Description = model.project.Description,
                    Start = model.project.Start,
                    End = model.project.End,
                    ProjectHead = model.project.ProjectHead,
                    Status = model.project.Status,
                    Technology = model.technology.TechnologyId.ToString()
                };
                _context.Add(project);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            return View(model);

        }
```

Comment: Your question is the partial view doesn't show the dropdown list filled with data?

Comment: no dropdown is shown but data doesn't saved

Comment: Can you share your `_Technologypartial` and view code for me to test？

Comment: okok i share in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select an option in Partial View, After submiting the form, You want save the value of option. I suggest you to use ViewModel to achieve it. Refer to this simple demo:

I simplified your class for testing convenience.

```
public class Project
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string? Technology { get; set; }
    }

public class Technology
    {
        public int TechnologyId { get; set; }
        public string? TechnologyName { get; set; }
    }
```

Create a View model to pass the value.

```
public class PartialViewData
    {
        public PartialViewData()
        {
            project = new Project();
            technology = new Technology();  
        }
        public Project project { get; set; }
        public Technology technology { get; set; } 
    }
```

**DbContext**

```
 public class MvcMovieContext : DbContext
    {
        public MvcMovieContext(DbContextOptions<MvcMovieContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Technology> technology { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        
        private readonly MvcMovieContext _context;

        public HomeController(MvcMovieContext context)
        {
           
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            var list =  _context.technology.ToList();
             
            List<SelectListItem> dropdown = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach(var item in list)
            {
                dropdown.Add(new SelectListItem()
                {
                   Text = item.TechnologyName,
                   Value = item.TechnologyId.ToString()
                }) ;
            }

            PartialViewData model = new PartialViewData();
            ViewBag.Technology = dropdown;
            return View(model);
        }



[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Privacy(PartialViewData model)
{
     Project project = new Project()
          {
              Name = model.project.Name,
              Technology = model.technology.TechnologyId.ToString()
          };
    
                //......
    
     return View();
}
}
```

**View**

```
@model PartialViewData

<form method="post">
    <input asp-for="@Model.project.Name" />

    <div class="row">
        <partial name="_Technologypartial" model="@Model.technology" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

**_Technologypartial**

```
@model Technology

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label>Technology</label>
        <br />
        <select name="technology.TechnologyId" class="form-control" asp-items=@ViewBag.Technology>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo:

[image]

Edit=================

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
     var list =  _context.technology.ToList();

        List<SelectListItem> dropdown = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach(var item in list)
        {
            dropdown.Add(new SelectListItem()
            {
               Text = item.TechnologyName,
               Value = item.TechnologyId.ToString()
            }) ;
        }

        PartialViewData model = new PartialViewData();
        ViewBag.Technology = dropdown;
        return View(model);
}
    

    
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(PartialViewData model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //change here
            var name = _context.Technology.Where(x => x.TechnologyId == model.technology.TechnologyId).Select(x => x.TechnologyName).FirstOrDefault();
            Project project = new Project()
            {
                ProjectId = model.project.ProjectId,
                ProjectName = model.project.ProjectName,
                Description = model.project.Description,
                Start = model.project.Start,
                End = model.project.End,
                ProjectHead = model.project.ProjectHead,
                Status = model.project.Status,

                //change here
                Technology = name
            };
            _context.Add(project);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

         return View(model);
        
    }
```

**View**

```
@model PartialViewData



    <div class="row">
        <partial name="_Technologypartial" model="@Model.technology" />
    </div>
```

**_Technologypartial**

```
@model Technology

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label>Technology</label>
        <br />
        <select name="technology.TechnologyId" class="form-control" asp-items=@ViewBag.Technology>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you give solution using database through `viewbag`

Comment: @gourav kumar I have edited my answer to use database instead of hard code. Hope it can help you. Actually just use `var list =  _context.technology.ToList();` to replave `hard code`

Comment: `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error occurred

Comment: check my answer, you need instantiate the viewmodel and pass it from controller to view in get method, Then in viewmodel, you need instantiate it's properties in Constructor.

Comment: i do all things but again it show null reference

Comment: THe error appears in `<partial name="_Technologypartial" model="@Model.technology" />` right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245357/discussion-between-xinran-shen-and-gourav-kumar).

Comment: yes in `<partial name="_Technologypartial" model="@Model.technology" />`

Comment: I edited my answer to provide the whole code, you can refer to this.

Comment: Hi @gourav kumar, Please check the answer i update.

Comment: yes i try but when i save data it show id not Name

Comment: i update in question

Comment: if you want to save name instead of id,you just need change  ’Value = item.TechnologyName’  in foreach()

Comment: after change it will again show null reference

Comment: Actually, we select the name and save id in database, because in generally, we use id as foreign key right? So TechnologyId is the fk between project and technology table,if you want to get name, you can just select name by this id.

Comment: Because the name and id has been saved in Technology table, So Project table just need TechnologyId as fk. The table design is very reasonable now in your project.

Comment: If you want to save name in project table, you can select name by id in technology table and then save name in project table in your post method.

Comment: IF you want to show name, YOu can provide the view and controller code, I can help you to change your code.

Comment: yeah i upate the question

Comment: @gourav kumar , plesase check , I have updated post method in my answer.

Comment: Done working Now

Comment: and i have another one in this method i made this dropdown into multi select list